# Releasing an object with NSDate object as property

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsdate

I created an object with a `NSDate` property like this:

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject { NSDate *date_ }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;
```

**MyClass.m**

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize date=date_;

-(id) init
{
if (self=[super init])
    date_ = [NSdate date];

return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
[date_ release];
date_ = nil;
}
```

But when I create this object

```
[[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when my thread calls `objc_release`:

If I add a retain on init:

```
 -(id) init
{
if (self=[super init])
{
    date_ = [NSdate date];  
    [date_ retain];
}
return self;
}
```

It seems to be working fine, but isn't declaring the property with "retain" supposed to retain it for me ?

Comment: [AT]property (nonatomic, retain) will retain if you do self.date = [NSDate date] because the setter will retain it. also [AT]property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date; is enough you dont need to declare anything else even [AT]synthesize is not necessary unless you want a specific var name instead of the default _date that will be generated for you.

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas Manzini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `date` (the Ivar) you circumvent the setters' retain - which is what you would do in your init method (don't use setters/getters in init but access iVar directly).
Since `[NSDate date]` returns an autoreleased object, you have to retain it.

To use the setter you would need to call the setter method (either `self.date` or `[self setDate:]`). In this case the object gets retained by the setter automatically.
Do this everywhere except in your init and dealloc.

Also I guess there is a typo since in your init you use `date` as iVar where it should be `date_` as defined by your synthesize. **this has been edited to be now correct in the OP**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Out of curiosity, why shouldn't I use setters in init ? For instant, if I'd like to set a string to something like str_ = @"something" it would be be easier than to have to retain it ?

Comment: It is a convention, though most of the time it might not cause harm. See this answer and search on SO - there are many answers to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856672/objc-using-self-in-init-and-or-initwithframe/11856820#11856820 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc

Comment: Also consider switching to ARC with any new projects. It is good to know about manual reference counting of course, but ARC makes a lot easier

Comment: Thanks. I'm working with Cocos2D and it's not using ARC yet, (as far as I last checked).